# cannot connect to template1: FATAL: role "_postgres" does not exist

Tags: macos, postgresql

Working on OS X 10.10, installed postgreSQL and PostGIS from
[here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres), psql vers 9.3.5. I am having a hard time getting postgreSQL running.

I try to follow the OSM tutorial on psql and PostGis. But that seems rather hard... I am stuck [here](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/postgres).
They suggest to create the user like:

```
sudo -u postgres createuser christoph
```

That did not work for me. I created the user like this:

```
$ sudo -u _postgres createuser -U postgres christoph
```

That worked without any problems. Then I tried this:

```
$ sudo -u _postgres createdb --encoding=UTF8 --owner=christoph gis
> cannot connect to template1: FATAL:  role "_postgres" does not exist
```

How can `_postgres` not exist if I just created a role with it?!

I also do not understand why

```
$ createdb mydb
> -bash: createdb: command not found
```

does not work although
I added the path like:

```
$ export PSQL_DIR=/usr/local/pgsql/bin/
$ export PATH="$PSQL_DIR:$PATH"
```

before.

Executing the command like:

```
$ /usr/local/pgsql/bin/createdb mydb
> createdb: cannot create database: ERROR:  permission denied to create database
```

I am looged in with the user who installed psql...
Is that connected?!

Comment: `-bash: creatdb: command not found` You misspelled "create"

Comment: thats a typo :) but thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: It's a suspicious typo, though, because it appears in both the command and the error message, and would perfectly explain that error message. If you did type it right, try to copy and paste the actual command and error, rather than typing an  approximation. Although you should probably do so as a separate question, as this site doesn't work very well with two questions on one page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is very easy to confuse *system users* (stored in `/etc/passwd`) with *Postgres roles* (stored inside the database cluster).

In your first command, you mention *both* types of user:

- `sudo -u _postgres` means "use the system user `_postgres` to execute the following command"
- the `-U postgres` in the command means "connect to the Postgres cluster with the role `postgres`"

However, in the next command:

```
sudo -u _postgres createdb --encoding=UTF8 --owner=christoph gis
```

You specify the same `sudo -u _postgres`, but are missing the `-U` argument to the actual Postgres command (you say you want christoph to own the new DB, but you don't say "I am christoph").

The Postgres command-line tools have a default behaviour of guessing that the Postgres role name is the same as the system user name. Since the system user is named `_postgres` (with leading underscore) and the Postgres role is named `postgres` (no leading underscore), this assumption fails, and you can't connect.

Comment: Okay. So I basically did not create a new user called `christoph` (one like `_postgres`) but a role called `christoph`? Where would be the difference?  With "next command" you mean that one `$ sudo -u _postgres createdb --encoding=UTF8 --owner=christoph gis` ? What I try to do is creating a new database in which I can store my data... I am sorry. I am very new to databases and feel very lost with all the "word" like systemuser, role, database, cluster etc. Is there anything where I could read on that? I guess that would solve many problems I have..

Comment: @Stoffer You created a role called Christoph, but you then didn't use it to connect in the next command, which would require `-U christoph`, not just `--owner christoph` (you need to say "I am christoph" not just "I am somebody creating on behalf of christoph"). This might be clearer if you just get an interactive prompt with `psql -U christoph postgres` and issue `Create Database` etc from there.

Comment: Ah, okay. So the `postgres` in `psql -U christoph postgres` is refering to the `postgres cluster`. I should be able to access that cluster with the role `christoph`. While `_postgres` is a system user which is some sort of an admin?

Comment: @Stoffer Yep, that's about the size of it.